# How to add zend debugger support for PHP in windows?

Tags: php, windows, zend-debugger

I don't want to install Zend Server,

and it doesn't work by simply adding this line in php.ini:

```
zend_extension_ts=.\ZendDebugger.dll
```

Comment: what do you want to achive? to get Zend debugger enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You may check [this](http://www.devcha.com/2008/01/how-to-install-zend-debugger-on-windows.html) manual. I hope it's help you